# Cannot install Recess php framework

Tags: php, recess

I wanted to use recess php framework, but i just cannot install it. whenever i try, It is giving me [THIS](http://dreamer.in/space/error.png) error.

One of the answer in the previous question was to redownload from the git repo of the library. 
i tried that several times on 3 different servers.

Can anyone help me pointing out what exactly is the error or how can i get around it.

Comment: You have invalid configuration.

Comment: if you are talking about **recess-conf.php** then i have done the asked changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a routing error. At what point in the installations does it throw this error?

1. try checking that you have php mod_rewrtie enabled
2. make sure you have write permissions to the directories specified in the docs
3. make sure that www-data owns the web directory you are installing in

Let me know if you need any more help. Im really proficient at Recess